# Is dare a modal or main verb in this sentence and how to identify it?

Tags: modal-verbs, semi-modals

I can identify "dare" as modal in negative and interrogative sentence but find it difficult to identify in  assertive sentence. for example

> John dares to call a spade a spade.

Comment: **dare** in this case is used intransitively (and not as an auxiliary verb). It's much like **fear** in the sentence *He feared to touch the mysterious object.*

Comment: Your sentence looks correct, but doesn't seem to match @fev's comment on it. Did you edit the sentence?

Comment: Yes it was a mistake ,but my point was always about identification- in negative and interrogative I know. but in positive sentence I have dilemma

Comment: In your example, "dare" is a lexical verb, not a modal. Lexical "dare" occurs mostly in non-affirmative contexts, but is not restricted to them, as your example demonstrates.

Comment: Now that's a  good point. Have no meaning of its own but used for emphasis but  it mean the same intention when used as "modal ". John dare call a spade a spade- as modal

Comment: Modal vs lexical _dare_ an ELL topic?

Answer (score 3):

Your sentence is not correct. According to [Collins](https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/easy-learning/dare-and-need)

> When ***dare*** is used ***as a modal verb in a positive statement***,
> ***there must be a word of negative meaning in the same clause***. This word can be outside the verb phrase and may be a word with a
> negative sense, such as ***only***, ***never***, ***hardly***.
>
> ***No*** sensible driver ***dare*** risk that chance.

In your sentence there is no negative marker, so it should be either

> John dare***s*** to call a spade a spade.

or

> John dare***d*** to call a spade a spade.

In both cases, the verb ***to dare*** is used as a main verb, not as a modal.

Basically, the general rule may be formulated more clearly in this way:

> As a modal verb, ***dare*** is used ***in negative*** and ***interrogative sentences***; it is followed by a bare infinitive:
>
> - I ***daren't think*** how many victims there are.
> - How ***dare*** she ***criticise*** us? ([grammaring.com](https://www.grammaring.com/the-semi-modal-dare))

Comment: What about the expression "I dare say"? That looks like a modal, and doesn't require a negative.

Comment: Thank you for pointing to this exception. Yes, this is a rare case when **dare** is a modal verb used in an affirmative sentence. And this [link](https://sites.google.com/site/myenglishness/home/use-of-english/issemi-modalsmodalverbsp14) proves you right. However, most sources will say that "as a modal verb, _dare_ is used [and I should probably add _**almost always**_ in negative and interrogative sentences."

Comment: There are many exceptions ,I have seen 1\4 sentences like that of total. However I am sorry to miss 's' in dares and whoa that gives me answer for this the 's' differentiator for verb .but that doesn't help in java latte case 'i' ‍♂️

Comment: One more does "neednt" follow same pattern as "darent" by mr. Fev.Now don't point that missing ' .  haha

Comment: In "I dare say", "dare is not a modal but a lexical verb, cf' "He dares say" / "I didn't dare say".

Comment: @BillJ So the link from my comment is wrong? I find instances of **He dare say** in the [Hansard](https://hansard.parliament.uk/Commons/1883-07-20/debates/255e2b2a-3109-41a0-90de-0611aa00d1dd/HullBarnsleyAndWestRidingJunctionRailwayAndDock(Interest)Bill), is it a mistake there too?

Comment: The fact that "dare" takes _do_-support in primary verb negation and subject-aux inversion seems to prove it's lexical in that example. Grammar has changed somewhat in the last 100 years!

Comment: @BillJ I must say it can be confusing sometimes :-)